# How to use the format function in PostgreSQL when I have % in the string?

Tags: postgresql, format, plpgsql

I have a function which combine multiple parameters in a string if they're not null or empty. On specific parameters I use the % character for LIKE conditions.
My problem is the format function which try to perform a transformation on it like if it was a parameter. How can I avoid this ?

I have 10+ tests on parameters and multiple LIKE.
In the example below the second FORMAT function try to convert the % in TEST%

```
_nom_personne_like := 'TEST%';
_type_activite_personne := 'SOMETHING';
IF _nom_personne_like != '' THEN
    _query := _query || ' AND personne_planning.nom_personne LIKE %L ';
    _query := FORMAT(_query,_nom_personne_like);
END IF; 
IF _type_activite_personne != '' THEN 
    _query := _query || ' AND personne_planning.type_activite = %L ';
    _query := FORMAT(_query,_type_activite_personne);
END IF;`
```

The message returned by the server is : Conversion type specifier « ' » unrecognized
I have already try to double the %, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer `format()` over string concatenation due to better readability. 
I follow the rule not to use a variable as the first parameter of the function. 
Your code could look like this:

```
_nom_personne_like := 'TEST%';
_type_activite_personne := 'SOMETHING';
IF _nom_personne_like != '' THEN
    _query := 
        format(
            '%s AND personne_planning.nom_personne LIKE %L ', 
            _query,
            _nom_personne_like);
END IF; 
IF _type_activite_personne != '' THEN 
    _query := 
        format(
            '%s AND personne_planning.type_activite = %L ',
            _query,
            _type_activite_personne);
END IF;`
```

Comment: I prefer the use of FORMAT() for query construction over || and it's working like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just forget about the `format()` function like so:

```
_nom_personne_like := 'TEST%';
_type_activite_personne := 'SOMETHING';
IF _nom_personne_like != '' THEN
    _query := _query || ' AND personne_planning.nom_personne LIKE ' ||
              quote_literal(_nom_personne_like);
END IF; 
IF _type_activite_personne != '' THEN 
    _query := _query || ' AND personne_planning.type_activite = ' ||
              quote_literal(_type_activite_personne);
END IF;
```